# Most appropriate way to deal with my own bad question

Tags: discussion

Here is the question in question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26183720/php-class-methods-cant-see-class-members

Asking a question like this doesn't contribute to the SO community in any way and floods out good questions although it wasn't apparent to me at that time.

Unfortunately someone answered it before I realized how bad it was and I am no longer able to delete the question. Although the answer was helpful to me I don't think it will benefit anyone else.

Should I flag it?

Should I obsessively watch for answers and delete questions if they reveal any obvious SO no no's before they can be up voted?

Should I edit the question so that it is more general/addresses a broader problem/etc and also makes the current answers confusing and irrelevant?

Answer (score 3):

> Should I obsessively watch for answers and delete questions when I realize my mistake before any answers can be upvoted?

I don't know about *obsessively*. I've not asked many questions but I thought you get a notification when an answer is posted. It is generally a good idea to take a look at an answer quickly after it is posted because they can show problems with your question. For instance, first answerer misinterpret a tricky bit of the question and then everybody who answers afterwards operates from this misinterpretation. I've seen this happen a few times. Then the OP has to tell everyone that they did not understand the question.

If you do realize that you posted a terrible question and you still have the opportunity to delete it, then yes, please delete it rather than let it sit there for rep farmers to use and for us to vote to close and vote to delete. The only caveat here is that folks who have *a habit* of posting bad questions can earn a ban by deleting questions. ("a habit" is the key phrase.)

But you can't delete, so you could flag with a custom flag, explain why your question is worthy of deletion, and ask for deletion. I think a moderator would accept, seeing as this is a typo question and has no lasting value. They might also check your flagging history to make sure you have not made a habit of this. (Maybe there's a reason I don't know that would generally prevent a moderator from deleting the question. Mods, if that's the case, please tell me.)

If deletion is refused for some reason, then you could ask for dissociation.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I managed to duplicate a question (despite searching for it). For that question the best remedy was to flag it for deletion with a note to the mod re why it should be deleted.

I don't think that there can be a hard and fast answer for all such questions as each one will need to be a judgment call. If it adds value then leave it up. If it adds nothing then delete it/flag for deletion.